# how to Ignore characters other than [a-z][A-Z]

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I ignore characters other than [a-z][A-Z] in input string in python, and after applying method what will the string look like?

Do I need to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use a regex, use a negative character class (`[^...]`):

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', inputtext)
```

A negative character class matches anything *not* named in the class.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = 'The quick brown fox!'
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', inputtext)
'Thequickbrownfox'
```

But using `str.translate()` is *way* faster:

```
import string
ascii_letters = set(map(ord, string.ascii_letters))
non_letters = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256) if i not in ascii_letters)
inputtext.translate(None, non_letters)
```

Using `str.translate()` is *more than 10 times faster* than a regular expression:

```
>>> import timeit, partial, re
>>> ascii_only = partial(re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]').sub, '')
>>> timeit.timeit('f(t)', 'from __main__ import ascii_only as f, inputtext as t')
7.903045892715454
>>> timeit.timeit('t.translate(None, m)', 'from __main__ import inputtext as t, non_letters as m')
0.5990171432495117
```

Using Jakub's method is slower still:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(c for c in t if c not in l)", 'from __main__ import inputtext as t; import string; l = set(string.letters)')
9.960685968399048
```

Comment: That `*` is redundant

Comment: @JonClements: it makes the replacement a little more efficient; rather than replace each and every character individually with the empty string, it replaces *groups* of matching characters with the empty string.

Comment: @JonClements: Ick. `timeit` shows that adding `*` significantly slows this down. Removed.

Comment: +1 for testing my snippet, and for `translate()`. I am surprised that my comprehension is slower than regex. Apparently time to read ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124)

Comment: @JakubM.: you can shave off 0.5 second on a million runs by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression (so `''.join([...])`, but that is still slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]').sub('', your_string)
```

You could also manage without regular expressions (e.g, if you had regex phobia):

```
import string
new_string = ''.join(c for c in old_string
                     if c not in set(string.letters))
```

Although I would use regex, this example has additional educational values: [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), [comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) library. Note that `set` is not strictly needed here

Comment: Your regular expression would be faster, see my answer. :-)